# what is the best way to design the skeleton of springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am writing a springboot application that should calculate the grade of a student. You should read the name of the student from command line, and call an API that will return the student ID in JSON. Then I will take the Student ID and call another API that would return the total of the student Marks in JSON. Then I should calculate the grade accordingly. The calculation is as follow: F=<60, D=<65, C=< 75, B=<85, A=<100.
Below is my hypothetical view of how I will write the project, I think I know how to write the code that will function, but I am stuck with what is the best skeleton for the project or design of classes. Below is how I think it should be written.

```
@Controller
// Rest call to the Student API
public class StudentController {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientController.class);
    private RestOperations rest;
    private Config config;  //to read the URL
    .....
```

---

```
    @Controller
// Rest call to the grades API
public class GradsController 
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientController.class);
    private RestOperations rest;
    private Config config; //to read the URL
    .....
```

---

```
Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="api.call")
public class Config {
    private String URL;
    .....
```

---

```
   public class Student {
    @JsonProperty("Data")
    private Elements[] elements;
    .......
```

---

```
 public class Grads {
        @JsonProperty("Subjects")
        private String[] subjects;
        .......
```

---

```
@Service
public class CalculateGrade {
    private String marks;
    private HashMap <String, Integer> gradeMap;

    CalculateGrade( String marks)
    {
        this.marks = marks;
        this.carName = carName;
        fillMap();
    }
    private void fillMap()
    {
        gradeMap= new HashMap<>();
        gradeMap.put("A",100);
        gradeMap.put("B", 85 );
       ..........
     }
     public String getGrade()
    {
      // do calculations;
    }
```

---

```
    @SpringBootApplication 
    @ConfigurationPropertiesScan ("Config") 
    public class MyApplication {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication.class);     
    @Autowired  StudentController StudentController;

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
         SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);

    }
```

Comment: If that is your take on how it should be written, then what is the actual problem ?

Comment: my problem is in the project skeleton and if there is a better structure

Answer (score 0):

For a skeleton, it looks quite sensible. Controllers to translate from Web to Domain and the business logic in domain/application services (CalculateGrade). Looks a lot like the Hexagonal architecture ("Ports&Adapters").

Comment: thanks for your input. and what do you think about storing the grads in map? would it make more sense to put in a properties file or enum?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with them.